# Using AutoMerge Editing - things aren't merging, what isn't right?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I have checked the AutoMerge Editing box in the Mesh menu, and dragged faces so they are as closely lined up as I can make them, and clicked Remove Doubles in order to adjust the merge distance to wider. Still I can almost never get things to merge. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: For me, It wont work when proportional editing is on.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The default automerge distance is very small, as it's usually used with [*Vertex Snapping*](http://blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/snap.html#transform-snapping).

To use vertex snapping, set the snapping mode to *Vertex* (<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>):

[image]

Then hold <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd> while transforming vertices (or toggle the magnet icon in *3D view > Header*)

Now automerge should work as expected:

[image]

---

To increase the automerge distance, adjust the *Double Threshold* in *3D view > Tool Shelf* (<kbd>T</kbd>) *> Option > Mesh Options*:

[image]