# Is there a way to adjust the radius for AutoMerge welding verts?

Tags: modeling, mesh, interface

I'm retopologizing a mesh I created in Blender and I'm trying to use AutoMerge to merge verts by dragging them close to each other. Unfortunately, the radius of effect that AutoMerge uses is very tight and I have to fiddle with moving the vert around so much before it merges that it's wasting time. If I could adjust the distance that AutoMerge uses to decide when to weld verts my workflow would be so much smoother. Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ask a question, find the answer yourself:

[Using AutoMerge Editing - things aren't merging, what isn't right?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39078/using-automerge-editing-things-arent-merging-what-isnt-right?rq=1)

Go into Edit Mode - Tool Shelf - Option Tab on the left - change Double Threshold

Comment: Why not just turn on vertex snapping?

Comment: When retopologizing the snapping is to Face and changing it to vertex to snap a vert and then back to face is rather slow as well.

Comment: So wait to snap verts until you need to snap a bunch of them and use the Ctrl+Tab menu to switch between snapping modes. I guarantee it's easier than trying to manually position them next to each other by hand.